# Very large graphs with d3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to support large graphs (50k-200k nodes). D3 force layout is extremely slow with its "tick" operation. Each tick take a few seconds.
I wonder if one these is possible:

1. Splitting the loading (doing for example 10 ticks, draw and after that do the rest one at the time)
2. Handling only with the "heavy nodes" and just throw their neighbors to somewhere close.
3. Running something similar to d3 forcelayout at the server and just send the UI the final positions

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/01ab2e85e8727d6529d20391c0fd9a16) it achieves greater performance using web workers and canvas instead of SVG. **But** you are really hitting the limit of what `d3` is going to be able to handle.  (Seriously, at 200K nodes is the diagram even comprehensible?)

Comment: What is these web workers? Do you have any jsfiddle with code like this so I can try it myself? Anyway, will it be wrong to assume that even this will not support more than 10-20k of nodes?

Comment: [Read all about web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).  The code I link to is a fully reproducible example, I've cut and pasted into plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9wuOmaPpgEaTdt7Su7gi?p=preview) and upped the nodes to 20K.  Takes around 40 seconds on my machine to generate the force layout.

Comment: At that scale you may have a so-called "hairball" that is uninterpretable by human beings, even with web workers.